# How do I sending messages from Passenger and Bunny to RabbitMQ?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, passenger

I use Rabbitmq with the Bunny gem to store messages that we want to send to customers. I have a Padrino-based web service that pushes messages to the queue and many workers that consume messages.

It works fine when I use Thin as the server, but I get an "execution expired" message from Bunny if I start the web-service in Apache/Passenger. I read there's a problem with EventMachine in Passenger, but Bunny doesn't use EventMachine, so it might be a different issue, although the behavior is very similar.

The exception is "execution expired", so it's waiting for a message that never arrives, so I guess there can be a callback issue, although the code is very simple. Bunny opens a channel to RabbitMQ, pushes the message and closes the channel, so there's no polling and doesn't call any callbacks.

The code in the service is:

```
client = Bunny.new
client.start
client.create_channel  # => throws exception, "execution expired"
...
```

Comment: Bunny might not use EventMachine, but it's sure using threads, which might be colliding the same way that EventMachine does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a Passenger issue, because I binded the client instance to the class and wanted to use the same connection over multiple requests. It worked in thin, but Passenger didn't like this solution.

Comment: just passing by to remember you to mark as the answer ;)

Comment: I'm having this same problem. You identified the problem, but what was your solution?

Comment: I stored the connection instance in a class variable, but in Passenger it's not a safe solution. So finally I reconnected to RabbitMQ in each web request. It's not too efficient but stable.

Comment: Passenger has a [`#starting_worker_process`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_smart_spawning_caveat_1_unintentional_file_descriptor_sharing) hook, which allows you to reset the Bunny connection in the spawned process.